# How can I adjust this UV map edge?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to project a video texture onto a convex television screen. For some reason, no matter how I adjust the mesh edges on the left, that black strip is still showing. I don't think I have a good understanding about how the unwrapping works, especially since I see all these outlier edges isolated from the main screen area. I've experimented with Smart UV Project, but sometimes, it produces edges on the map I can't correlate back to the tv-screen's selected face. Would appreciate any feedback since I just started using Blender. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

10/30/20 - Added a picture to show defect more clearly.

[image]

10/30/20 - FIXED! Had to switch the material of those defect edges per @Jachym Michal's advice!

Comment: Hello :). The black stripe seems to perfectly fit the triangles. Isn't it a different (black) material? :)

Comment: @Jachym Michal, I'm not sure. How can I check if it's a different material? The tv model was imported from sketchfab, so I am not too familiar with how it was constructed. Thanks!

Comment: Sure :). Simply select a triangle in the black part, and the node editor will show the assigned material :). I noticed you have two material slots, it's possible one of them has a different material that's causing you the trouble.

Comment: @JachymMichal, it worked!!! I am so happy. Thank you so much!